# Appending query string with multiple filters

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5, query-string, laravel-routing

I have a filter bar that searches one filter at a time. However, I would like for it to do is select multiple filters at once. My links for the filters all currently have a single query string. Is there a way to append the query string with another query?

Currently, I set up my filters in a controller like the code below.

```php
$products = new Product();
$queries = [];

$columns = [
    'beertype_id', 'packaging', 'brewery_id'
];

foreach ($columns as $column) {
    if (request()->has($column)) {
        $products = $products->where($column, request($column));
        $queries[$column] = request($column);
    }
}

$products = $products->paginate(10)->appends($queries);
```

Then I want to call them in the Blade template.

```
<p>Filter Products:</p>
<a href="/products">Reset</a>
<ul>
    <p>Types of Beer:</p>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?beertype_id=1">IPA</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?beertype_id=2">Lager</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?beertype_id=3">Pale Ale</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <p>Packaging:</p>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?packaging=bottle">Bottle</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?packaging=can">Can</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?packaging=keg">Keg</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <p>Brewery:</p>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?brewery_id=2">Kinnegar</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?brewery_id=3">White Hag</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?brewery_id=4">Quilmes</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to have a query string like 
`?beertype_id=3&beertype_id=5&brewery_id=2`. When the user clicks on the filters individually, how can I add the new filter on each time? An example would be, if a user clicked "IPA," all IPA products would appear and then if they clicked "Porter," both Porter AND IPA products would appear.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Pass Array In Query:

```
<p>Filter Products:</p>

<a href="/products">Reset</a>

<ul>
    <p>Types of Beer:</p>

    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?beertype_id[]=1&beertype_id[]=4" >IPA</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?beertype_id[]=2&beertype_id[]=5">Lager</a></li>
    <li class="filter-link"><a href="/products?beertype_id[]=3&beertype_id[]=6">Pale Ale</a></li>
</ul>
```

And Get This Array in Controller Like this

```
$products = new Product;


$queries = [];

$columns = [
    'beertype_id', 'packaging', 'brewery_id'
];

foreach ($columns as $column){
    if (request()->has($column)){
      if(is_array(request($column))){
        $products = $products->whereIn($column, request($column));
      } else {
        $products = $products->where($column, request($column));
      }

      $queries[$column] = request($column);
    }


}

$products = $products->paginate(10)->appends($queries);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this just gets whatever is in the href attribute, I am trying to get it so the query string changes to whichever product the user clicks on if that makes any sense? so if the user click on "IPA", only IPA products would appear, then if they click on "Porter", then all Porter AND IPA products would appear?